# If there are exactly 10,000 characters in Chinese, how many 2-character representations are there?

Tags: combinatorics

I am hoping I used the combinatorics formula appropriately and would like to have this peer reviewed.

I was asked:
"If there are exactly 10,000 characters in Chinese, how many 2-character representations are there?"

I used combinatorics:

$$\frac{n!}{!( − )!} = \frac{(10000)!}{2!(10000 − 2)!} = 4.9995 \times 10^7$$

Did I set this problem up correctly?

Per comments - The same character *can be used twice.* I apologize for any ambiguity. `AA` is valid, and `AB` and `BA` are valid, but each could only be counted once. i.e. for the small string: `AABC`:

`AA`, `AB`, `BC`, `CB`, `BA` would all be valid.

NOTE - This has not been submitted or checked by anybody else. I am working through "A First Course in Probability 8th Edition" by Sheldon Ross and am trying to teach myself.

How can I edit my current formula to match the rules for the example given above?

Comment: Can you use the same character twice?

Comment: I added information for clarity. The answer is yes @DavidDiaz

Comment: This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You computed the number of two-character combinations (where the characters are different). Thus for example you assumed that $AB$ and $BA$ are the same, and you also excluded $AA$.

Given that the same character can be used twice, your computation is not correct. If $AB$ and $BA$ are different, than you can simply choose any of the available $10,\!000$ characters in each position.

Comment: Sorry, I added more information for clarity @rogerl

Comment: I see your edit. ` If AB and BA are different, than you can simply choose any of the available 10,000 characters in each position.` How do I then find the total number of _possible_ combinations, assuming `AA` is valid, and `AB` and `BA` are different?

Comment: @JerryM.  Since repetition is permitted, each position can be filled in $10,000$ ways.  To find the number of two-character representations, use the [Multiplication Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product).

Answer (score 1):

Your question is similar to the following:

If there are exactly ten digits (0 through 9), how many 2-digit numbers are there (00 through 99)?

---

Since we use base ten, there are $10^2$ two-digit numbers and $10^3$ three-digit numbers and $10^7$ seven-digit numbers, etc... but what if we used a different base?

If there were ten thousand different symbols for the numbers one through ten thousand, how many numbers could be expressed with just two symbols?

Comment: Two-digit numbers do not have leading digit $0$.  You should say two-digit strings.

Comment: Non-negative integers representable with two digits or fewer*